# jQuery and Greensock animations -- animate all elements on screen with classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gsap

I'm trying to animate all elements that match the class "customers" on my page once they are scrolled into view.

My current version:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if(!$('.customers').hasClass('animated')) {
    if($('.customers').isOnScreen(0.45, 0.45)) {
      TweenMax.staggerTo($('.customer'), 0.3, {bottom:"+=50px", opacity:1,  ease: Power2.easeOut}, 0.15);
      $('.customers').addClass('animated');
    }
  }
})
```

Works to animate the first element when it enters the screen, and unfortunately as a result also animates the others while they are offscreen. What I want to happen is that each element that matches "customers" animates when it is scrolled into view.

(note that isOnScreen is a custom function that does element detection within the window).

I've tried using jquery's each function as such:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.customers').each(function( i ) {  
      if(!this.hasClass('animated')) {
        if(this.isOnScreen(0.45, 0.45)) {
          TweenMax.staggerTo($('.customer'), 0.3, {bottom:"+=50px", opacity:1,  ease: Power2.easeOut}, 0.15);
          this.addClass('animated');
        }
      }
})
```

And Ive also tried wrapping each "this" statement as a jquery element  as $(this).

I'm getting unexpected behavior in that the elements conitnue to animate as I scroll, even though they should have had their "animated" class removed (I want them to animate only the first time they enter the screen).

What I'm thinking I may need to do is create an array of customers, and then perform the TweenMax to each element in the array, but I'm not sure if this will work.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle of this? It is a little hard to imagine what you are really trying to do without a demo.

Comment: It's hard to get the greensock library to load here, but this is the gist of my page structure:
http://jsfiddle.net/jnstqchu/8/

Comment: can you also share your `.onScreen()` function for the thing to work? I see `TweenMax` loaded up just fine.

Comment: OK updated: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jnstqchu/10/

Comment: Is **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/ku2kyfow/)** anywhere close to what you were looking for?

Comment: That's precisely what I was going for! Thank you! Can you describe what you changed? Also, if you provide an answer I will select it as the right one.

Comment: Added details in an answer I just posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right here is what I think you needed to do.

- There had to be a listener for the `scroll` event on the `window` object to begin with in the first place of course. Stating the obvious.
- Then you loop through the `.customers` elements using an `each`.
- Then you check if *each* of those `.customers` elements already have a `animated` class on them. If, they do, then nothing happens but if they don't, the rest follows.
- The current `.customers` element is then checked if it is in a defined viewport area using the custom function `.isonScreen()`.
- Then `TweenMax` animates `.customer` elements found within the current `.customers` element that we are currently looping through. Notice the difference between `.customers`, the parent element, and the child `.cusotmer` elements. Remember, we are inside a loop, so each of the `.customers` element is looped through and then we further try to find `.customer` elements within each of them. The jQuery that helps us *find* inner `.customer` elements is: `$(this).find('.customer')`.
- Next up, in your CSS, `opacity: 0;` line was previously commented out for `.customer` elements. I uncommented it back on.
- We then use `.staggerFromTo` method of `TweenMax` to define a set of initial properties to begin our tween with, and end of another set of properties, all with a little bit of *stagger* between the animations so they don't just come up all the same time, neither do they wait for each other to finish before the next one plays. It is an overlapping animation.
- Another thing to note here is that we are animating `y` property of the elements which is a special property provided by `TweenMax` which is basically a short-cut to animate `translateY(...)` property as if you did that using CSS.
- Finally, you apply the `.animated` class on the currently looped `.customers` element.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.customers').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('animated')) {
            if ($(this).isOnScreen(0.45, 0.45)) {
                TweenMax.staggerFromTo($(this).find('.customer'), 0.3, {
                    y: 200,
                    opacity: 0
                }, {
                    y: 0,
                    opacity: 1,
                    ease: Power2.easeOut
                }, 0.15);
                $(this).addClass('animated');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/ku2kyfow/)** is the fiddle. Hope this helps.